# spring security stay on single url at login

Tags: authentication, spring-security

here is my case.

when first time user land to site, they will pointed to login page. (lest say http://ex.com/) and when they successfully login, they'll see the other page with the same url (http://ex.com/

but, when they open the site on other tab (http://ex.com) they will pointed back to login page.

how to implement this case in my site with spring security ?

its easy to do when deal with conventional servlet. i just need to have 2 method (doGet for showing login page, and doPost for authenticating user and if its valid it will call another view).

here is my configuration :

```
<security:http auto-config="true">        
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />                
    <security:form-login login-page="/login"
                         login-processing-url="/loginProcess" 
                         default-target-url="/login"
                         authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=1" />
    <security:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/logoutSuccess" />
</security:http>
```

Comment: Can you check whether the cookies are sent back to the server when the site is opened in new tab. Which browser are you using? It has to be some problem with the cookie. What is the expires value of the `JSESSIONID` cookie?

Comment: im sorry, i don't understand what is cookies related issues with my case?

Comment: In the second tab it is taking you to the login screen because your web client is sending back the authenticated session id when the resource is requested. The cookie `JSESSIONID` contains the authenticated session id.

Comment: thats the behaviour that i wanted. when user try to hit url (Which is the same as login page) in new tab, the site will show login page. not the resource page. how to make this behaviour in spring?

Comment: Can you share you spring security configuration? You need to set the property `default-target-url="<your default url>"`

Comment: @aurn, i post my configuration above. as you can see i try to point `default-target-url` as `login` page. so i need 1 url to handle it. but how to distinct the request from user (hit url from browser) and forwarding from spring security ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

** Edited (remove unrelated answer)

It appears you need to add a concurrent session management using Spring Security. See the following link: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/session-mgmt.html

You can inject the SessionRegistry and see if the principal is already logged-in. If he is, call the expireNow()

Or you can implement a filter on or before SessionManagementFilter  in the FilterChainProxy:

> The SessionManagementFilter checks the contents of the SecurityContextRepository against the current contents of the SecurityContextHolder to determine whether a user has been authenticated during the current request, typically by a non-interactive authentication mechanism, such as pre-authentication or remember-me [19]. If the repository contains a security context, the filter does nothing. If it doesn't, and the thread-local SecurityContext contains a (non-anonymous) Authentication object, the filter assumes they have been authenticated by a previous filter in the stack. It will then invoke the configured SessionAuthenticationStrategy.
>   - http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/session-mgmt.html

Comment: no, my question is not about how spring interact with ajax. but more likely how to keep url stay on one pattern. please read my question again. thanks :)

Comment: This must be a mistake. I must be answering a different question. My answer is totally way-off from the question. My bad. I need to find that post that asked the question that I was answering :)

Comment: the session of first tab must still. but the second tab will pointed to login page. and when they try to login with the same username, it will thrown out.

Comment: I see. So the second tab will just the login page regardless if the username and password is correct. Basically the user is stucked on the first tab. What happens if they close the browser while still logged on? How are they gonna logout since when you open a tab it shows the login page and regardless what you do you will still be in the login page

Comment: yes you are right. the case is intend to that behavior. and the user must wait until the session is invalid. you have any idea how to implement it at spring? actually i rewrite my code from conventional servlet to spring. and its really easy in to do with servlet.

Comment: What happens if the user refreshes the same tab? It should behave as if you created a new tab, right?

Comment: yes indeed. thats the behavior that my case need to implement. no body can refresh the page, they just will thrown out to login page if the do that.what my main concern is no single account can open more than one page at once with same account, and if they already login, no second attempt allowed to login again using same user id. spring is already give a feature with session management concurrency control for the second case. but for the first case, i don't know if it doable with spring security.

Comment: I have posted an answer in your question at the SpringSource forums. Can you check it out?

Answer (score 1):

I think your configuration has a problem

```
<security:http auto-config="true">        
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />                
    <security:form-login login-page="/login"
                         login-processing-url="/loginProcess" 
                         default-target-url="<home-page-url. ex: /home>"
                         authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=1" />
    <security:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/logoutSuccess" />
</security:http>
```

The `default-target-url` should point to the default page to which the application has to redirect after a successful login.

**EDITED**
After going through the required posted again, I think the approach is to make the controller handling `/login` request to handle both cases

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class AppsController {

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public ModelAndView view(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {

        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .getAuthentication();
        User user = authentication != null
                && authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof User ? (User) authentication
                .getPrincipal() : null;

        return user == null ? getLoginModelAndView() : getHomeModelAndView();
    }

    private ModelAndView getHomeModelAndView() {
        return null;
    }

    private ModelAndView getLoginModelAndView() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

If there is no authenticated user present in the session the controller will return the log-in page, but once the user is logged-in then it will return a different page.

Spring security will cache the logged used to the user session and it can be retrieved using the `SecurityContextHolder`.

Comment: That will not work still. Try creating a new tab. You're still able to log-in or access the same page.

Comment: Do you have the same url for the login page and the landing page after successful login? How did you implement your log-in controller? Does it have a GET and POST method handlers for /login url?

Comment: please read my question carefully. i need my login page same as url after user login. but with different view. and when user access the site from other tab, they will shown login page again. not the resource page like they see after login. this behavior is doable when using normal servlet. but i have no idea how to implement it using spring security. i have thought an idea, i will create another question.